# Using a while loop with objective oriented php programming

Tags: php

I am using the for each below with objective

```
$hierachy = new hierachy;
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new recursiveArrayIterator($hierachy->getSamelevelNode($name1)));
try {
   while($row = $hierachy->getSamelevelNode($name1)) {
  if(!isset($name1)) {
   $name1 = $row['left_node']+1; // First row = the node we searched from. First child's lft = lft+1.
  }
  if($row['left_node'] == $name1) { //This is a child of the searched node.
    echo $row['name'];
    $name1 = $row['right_node']+1; //next child's lft = this child's rgt + 1.
  }
} 

    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I don't have a fecht_Array function inside the functions.php I want to know how can I connect the function below with the while loop above with the function below.

```
    public function getSamelevelNode($node_name){
$stmt = conn::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT name,left_node,right_node
FROM categories
WHERE left_node = right_node AND name = :node_name
");
$stmt->bindParam(':node_name', $node_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

right now I am having trouble to know what function from the function in the while loop can be used to Fetch the data. I tried fetchALL but it seems.

In other words my function and the while loop are not working together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursive iterator, since you haven't nested arrays, for this.

Just use

```
while ($row == $hierachy->getSamelevelNode($name1)) {
    // use $row here
}
```

Comment: ok I understand Nested a array is done by Aliasing the same table and categorizing it into levels. so then is when the function recursive Iterator comes in.